# How to connect a MEMS Microphone Breakout - INMP401 to a RN-52 bluetooth module?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, differential, microphone, mems-microphone

I intended to use a  INMP401  ([MEMS MIC](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9868)) to capture audio and stream it via bluetooth using an RN-52 bluetooth module ([RN-52](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12849)). The RN-52 has inputs for differential +- signals.

The INMP outputs single channel audio peak to peak at approximately 200mV. I presumed that connecting this to the L+ input of the RN-52 via a 47nF capacitor and connecting the L- of the RN-52 to ground would allow me to capture audio. However the audio I receive is highly distorted and noisy.

I have tried to recreate the circuit shown here:

[image]

This however still remains unusable. Any advice on how to get the two devices connected effectively would be greatly appreciated. TIA.